# Certain line crashes syntax highlighting in Sublime

Tags: java, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I just realized that the following line

```
private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(a|b)\\d{3}");
```

is completely misunderstood by Sublime's Java syntax highlighting. The last quotation mark is regarded as the start of a `String` even though it's the end.

What shall I do about it?

**EDIT:** To reproduce the error try the following in Sublime:

```
public class SublimeBug{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 700308123417786640L;
    private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(a|b)\\d{3}");
    private final String a,b,c,d,e;
}
```

Comment: You should check that this is not caused by imbalanced quotes in your program or caused by a badly defined syntax color scheme. Pasting into my editor, [everything looks fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kdCCI.png)

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe See my edit.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Seems like a bug to me. I'd report it if I were you. Interestingly, it highlights correctly for me when I move that line into a method. If it's a real problem, you might consider making a constructor and initializing the value there instead. Or maybe look into using a [different editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs) ;)

Comment: File the bug, just don't call it 'crashes' because nothing crashes. Here's what looks like a pretty minimal case `Pattern.compile("(){");`

Answer (score 0):

This bug was [brought up in 2012](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9131) on the Sublime Text forums. The User facelessuser posted a fix for it, but it looks like it hasn't made its way into the latest version of Sublime Text yet.

> Starting at line 425 in the Java.tmLanguage, replace the entire "class-body" dict with this:

```
<key>class-body</key>
        <dict>
            <key>patterns</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>include</key>
                    <string>#comments</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>include</key>
                    <string>#class</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>include</key>
                    <string>#enums</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>begin</key>
                    <string>=</string>
                    <key>beginCaptures</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>name</key>
                            <string>keyword.operator.assignment.java</string>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <key>end</key>
                    <string>;</string>
                    <key>endCaptures</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>name</key>
                            <string>punctuation.terminator.java</string>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>patterns</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>include</key>
                            <string>#code</string>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>include</key>
                    <string>#methods</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>include</key>
                    <string>#annotations</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>include</key>
                    <string>#storage-modifiers</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>include</key>
                    <string>#code</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
```